# Make parts of UIView transparent by using a masking layer

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

Where the pink part is fixed and the grey area could possibly scroll. I have the following view structure:

[image]

I currently have this code:

```
extension FloatingPoint {

    var degreesToRadians: Self { return self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { return self * 180 / .pi }

} 

@IBDesignable
class MaskView: UIView {

    let startAngle: CGFloat = 180
    let endAngle: CGFloat = 0

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let multiplier: CGFloat = (frame.size.height * 3)
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height * multiplier),
                                  radius: frame.size.height * multiplier,
                                  startAngle: startAngle.degreesToRadians,
                                  endAngle: endAngle.degreesToRadians,
                                  clockwise: true).cgPath

        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }

}
```

The Mask View is set to have the grey background color.

The problem that I have is that the circular part is not transparent. Changing the color to `UIColor.clear` will only make the circular part to disappear. Am I fundamentally doing the wrong approach for this? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: May I ask how you change "the color to clear"? Could you show us your code for that?

Comment: I did that in the storyboard, but in code it would be `backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`

Comment: Multiplier should be 3 not `frame.size.height * 3`  `let multiplier: CGFloat = 3`

Comment: The cryptic multiplier was just me trying to figure out how to draw the circle equal for all screen widths, but that is a different story..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we need to create a subclass from `UIView` (which you already did). But here is the code that I used:

```
private extension FloatingPoint {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { return self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { return self * 180 / .pi }
}

@IBDesignable class MaskView: UIView {
    let startAngle: CGFloat = 180
    let endAngle: CGFloat = 0

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // The multiplier determine how big the circle is
        let multiplier: CGFloat = 3.0
        let radius: CGFloat = frame.size.width * multipler
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: radius)
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter,
                                      radius: radius,
                                      startAngle: startAngle.degreesToRadians,
                                      endAngle: endAngle.degreesToRadians,
                                      clockwise: true).cgPath
        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

Then you can add a `MaskView` as a subView in the `ViewController`. Make sure select the view assigned the class `MaskView` in the storyboard:

[image]

Now we have a very simply view hierarchy:

[image]

Compiles the code and it's looking great:

[image]

If you want a scrollable subview that is masked, add it as a subview of the maskView. Here is how the view hierarchy looks after this:

[image]

And finally, this is how it looks running in the simulator:

[image]

Ref: https://github.com/yzhong52/Example-LayerMask

Comment: Hi Yuchen, thanks. I tried your example but got the following results:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDGfz.png

Have the same view hierarchy as you and with the MaskView having a height of 150, pinned to leading, trailing and top.

Comment: @José, hard to tell what you did differently. I pushed my code here: https://github.com/yzhong52/Example-LayerMask. Hope that helps.

Comment: Had a slightly different view hierarchy. Good stuff, thanks!